# Postgres sql list all tables in a database

Tags: postgresql

"psql \dt information_schema" I am writing this command to see list of all tables and its asking ""Password for user information_schema:"" which Password should I provide ,I meadn I m providing the postgres as password.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing with the following command:

```
psql \dt information_schema
```

is to start psql and pass the name "information_schema" as the username to connect with.

The command `\dt information_schema` has to be entered **after** you have started psql and once you see the psql prompt.

If you want to run that directly from  the command line without waiting for the psql prompt, you need to use the -c switch:

```
psql -c "\dt information_schema.*" postgres postgres
```

All parameters and the order in which they are expected are listed when you run `psql --help` or have a look at the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

**Edit**

Here is a sample console session that shows you how to do this:

```
c:\>psql postgres postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql (9.0.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \dt information_schema.*
                        List of relations
       Schema       |          Name           | Type  |  Owner
--------------------+-------------------------+-------+----------
 information_schema | sql_features            | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_implementation_info | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_languages           | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_packages            | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_parts               | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_sizing              | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_sizing_profiles     | table | postgres
(7 rows)

postgres=# \dv information_schema.*
                            List of relations
       Schema       |               Name                | Type |  Owner
--------------------+-----------------------------------+------+---------
 information_schema | _pg_foreign_data_wrappers         | view | postgres
 information_schema | _pg_foreign_servers               | view | postgres
 information_schema | _pg_user_mappings                 | view | postgres
 information_schema | administrable_role_authorizations | view | postgres
 information_schema | applicable_roles                  | view | postgres
 information_schema | attributes                        | view | postgres
 information_schema | check_constraint_routine_usage    | view | postgres
 information_schema | check_constraints                 | view | postgres
 information_schema | column_domain_usage               | view | postgres
 information_schema | column_privileges                 | view | postgres
 information_schema | column_udt_usage                  | view | postgres
 information_schema | columns                           | view | postgres
 information_schema | constraint_column_usage           | view | postgres
 information_schema | constraint_table_usage            | view | postgres
 information_schema | data_type_privileges              | view | postgres
 information_schema | domain_constraints                | view | postgres
 information_schema | domain_udt_usage                  | view | postgres
-- More  --
```

And here is how to do it in one call:

```
c:\>psql -c "\dt information_schema.*" postgres postgres
Password for user postgres:
                        List of relations
       Schema       |          Name           | Type  |  Owner
--------------------+-------------------------+-------+----------
 information_schema | sql_features            | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_implementation_info | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_languages           | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_packages            | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_parts               | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_sizing              | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_sizing_profiles     | table | postgres
(7 rows)

c:\
```